# Enable SSH with a password instead of pem key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-cloudformation, ec2-ami

I am launching an EC2 instance using cloudformation. I want to enable SSH with a password instead of pem key for that instance. I am able to write the startup script (user data) to do this, but I have set the static password 'pass123' for user 'student'. I want to make this dynamic (random).
We would be happy with anything, really, other than SSH client certificate authentication.

Here is my cloudformation template:

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Description":"Password for instance",
   "Parameters":{
      "KeyName":{
         "Description":"Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair",
         "Type":"String"
      },
      "AWSAmiId":{
         "Description":"AMI Id to find",
         "Type":"String",
         "Default":"x86_64,amzn-ami-pv-2014.09.1.x86_64-ebs,amazon,ebs,paravirtual"
      }
   },
   "Resources":{
      "Ec2Instance":{
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
         "DependsOn":"Ec2SecurityGroup",
         "Properties":{
            "ImageId":{
               "Ref":"AWSAmiId"
            },
            "InstanceType":"t1.micro",
            "Tags":[
               {
                  "Key":"Name",
                  "Value":"MYINSTANCE"
               }
            ],
            "DisableApiTermination":"true",
            "SecurityGroupIds":[
               {
                  "Ref":"Ec2SecurityGroup"
               }
            ],
            "KeyName":{
               "Ref":"KeyName"
            },
            "UserData":{
               "Fn::Base64":{
                  "Fn::Join":[
                     "\n",
                     [
                        "#!",
                        "useradd student\n",
                        "echo pass123 | passwd student --stdin\n",
                        "echo \"student ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL\" | tee -a /etc/sudoers\n",
                        "mkdir /home/student/.ssh\n",
                        "cp cp ~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys ~student/.ssh/authorized_keys\n",
                        "sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config\n",
                        "service sshd reload\n"
                     ]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Ec2SecurityGroup":{
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
         "Properties":{
            "GroupDescription":"VPC Security Group",
            "SecurityGroupIngress":[
               {
                  "CidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0",
                  "FromPort":"22",
                  "IpProtocol":"tcp",
                  "ToPort":"22"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "Outputs":{
      "Password":{
         "Description":"newly created EC2 instance",
         "Value":"pass123"
      }
   }
}
```

Password could be:

- The filename of the SSH key
- The AMZN account ID (eg: 45678923)
- A random string (poiblkjfda)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I want to assign this password any random string, instead hard coded 'pass123'

Comment: Just use a different password in your User Data in the console. Or, if you trigger the launch from a script, have the script choose a password. Is your problem how to generate a random string, or how to include it in the User Data?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I am  looking for

1. How to generate a random string?
2. How to display in the stack output (include in the output section of cloud formation)?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to generate a random string as a password you can use **/dev/urandom**. For a 10 character string

```
head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 10 ; echo ''
```

You can include this in your user data instead of the static passphrase.

Comment: Thanks! But my next question is "How to display in the stack output (include in the output section of cloud formation)?"

Comment: PM me the question link, I'll take a look. Meanwhile, if the answer is correct, mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for *returning* the random password:

- You could generate it *prior* to calling CloudFormation. That is, whatever triggers CloudFormation could generate the password, and pass it to the stack as a Parameter. You can then show the Parameter as an Output.
- You could return the value as part of a [CloudFormation WaitCondition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitcondition.html), then show the result as an Output.
- You could generate the password in an [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html), which is then available to be inserted into the User Data and provided as an Output.
- You could configure the User Data to store the password in the [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/), which is more secure than showing it as a stack Output. The user would then retrieve the password themselves.

Only the first one is simple. The rest involve some configuration/coding.

Comment: Is there any sample snippet to do this? Becaus, I tried with defining Parameter but no luck. May be I am trying wrongly :(

Comment: You might be able to find something via a web search, but your need is fairly unique to your use-case. Try coding it yourself. If you encounter a problem, you can always post another question, showing your code and the problem you are experiencing.